# Cannot connect Internet if I run gzserver?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If I run gzserver, Internet doesn't work. And then, I use "sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart" to reconfigure the network setting, Internet is work. But once I run gzserver, it doesn't work again. (My OS is ubuntu 12.10.)

How to solve this problem(the gazebo and Internet are available together)?thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4247/cannot-connect-internet-if-i-run-gzserver?/) by [Sam](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/476/sam/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-08-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-08-30**:
how did you install gazebo?

**Comment by [Sam](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/476/sam/) on 2013-09-01**:
ok.because the network port conflict....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Answer in comments.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0